# Jquery UI Tabs, control variable lenght spent on each tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, controls, performance, tabs

I'm trying the following to control the speed of rotation of the tabs but with no luck, any ideas?

$('#featured').tabs({

```
onShow: function(event, ui) {

if(ui.index == 0)>

  { 
     $('#featured').tabs("rotate", 2000, true);
  }


  else if(ui.index == 1){    
     $('#featured').tabs("rotate", 5000, true);  
   }

  else if(ui.index == 2){

  $('#featured').tabs("rotate", 10000, true);

  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help your problem, but the callback is `show` not `onShow`.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show